# Amasty Extension - Sales Reps and Dealers - Change Dealers Programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, customer, customer-group

Extension **"Sales Reps and Dealers"** by Amasty

I have the **User ID of my customer and the Dealer ID of the Dealer** I want them to have, how can i programmatically change their dealer to the new one?

In my observer when a customer is successfully registered I grab their ID:

```
$customerId = $observer->getCustomer()->getId();
```

Then I load the customer with:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

At this point I also have the dealer's ID but don't know how to change the customer's dealer to that dealer.  It **doesn't show as an attribute** when I **var_export the $customer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following php code:

```
Mage::getModel('amperm/perm')->assignOneCustomer($uid, $cid);
```

where:

```
$uid - dealer (user) entity id;
$cid - customer entity id.
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Does it matter if I'm trying to do this in an event observer when a customer is successfully registered?

Comment: Wait it may work let me do some testing before up voting your answer